# Doxygen doesn't display any of the special comments

Tags: c++, doxygen

I've decided to document the code for my project. I found this tool *Doxygen* online and downloaded it.

But when I try to actually create an HTML file, it just displays the project contents and none of the special comments above the function.

I tried all types of comments -  `/*! ... */`  ,  `/** ... */` , `///`,`//!`

It displays only the name of a function and its definition in the `.h` file, like this:

[image]

How can I fix this? How can I enable Doxygen to display the special comments too?

Comment: By reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen by itself is a very efficient tool, but you have to learn how to use it. The key is the configuration file. The command:

```
doxygen -g
```

Will generate for you a default one in the current folder. You then need to edit it, either directly using any text editor, either through a GUI program that is name `doxywizard`. The default options values are usually a good start, but maybe you switched something ?

This commenting style should work:

```
/// define foo
#define foo 42

/// a truely efficient function
void foobar();

struct A {
    int b; ///< this is something
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are just using these special markers on code comments placed in the usual way inside functions?  Check that your front-end isn't using

> **`HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS`**
>
> If the `HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS` tag is set to `YES`, doxygen will hide any documentation blocks found inside the body of a function. If set to `NO` these blocks will be appended to the function's detailed documentation block.
>
> The default value is: `NO`.

You also probably want to enable

> **`EXTRACT_ALL`**
>
> If the `EXTRACT_ALL` tag is set to `YES` doxygen will assume all entities in documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available. Private class members and static file members will be hidden unless the `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` respectively `EXTRACT_STATIC` tags are set to `YES`.
>
> Note
>
> This will also disable the warnings about undocumented members that are normally produced when `WARNINGS` is set to `YES`.
>
> The default value is: `NO`.

I haven't specifically tested whether comments in a function body count as "documentation was available", but if you don't have parameter documentation in the doxygen format, I'd definitely turn on `EXTRACT_ALL`.